# wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003 error - UIAlertView with UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: iphone, spinner, uialertview, delay

I hoped that the answers to [squeezemylime's question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4241894) would solve my problem as I also have a UIAlertView without text field but it did not work out well. Instead of a text field I placed a UIActivityIndicatorView animating on it and no buttons used on creation. So the alert gets programmatically dismissed so that the delegate method destroys the spinner on the alert and the alert itself (which has been retained through the time running).

So, I'm getting also these **wait_fences:** messages within the debugger and I'm frozen in the meantime because everything I tried including the valuable hints in this thread won't kill these **wait_fences:** messages. There is no crash, neither with GDB nor on the device.

Stepping through the code I realized that **wait_fences:** message is shown directly after the delegate for **dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO** releases the questionable UIAlertView. Then I thought it could be similar to *squeezemylime*'s delay technique and did this:

```
[theAlertObj performSelector:@selector(dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
```

and the **wait_fences:** message was gone! But the call to **dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:** can't be satisfied because it is missing the second argument **animated:NO** - so I tried it with some changes implementing a method for the call:

```
- (void)dismissNamedAlert: (UIAlertView*)alert
{
    [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
}

- (void)postProcessLogicalWork: (id)arg
{
    [self performSelector:@selector(dismissNamedAlert:) withObject:theAlertObj afterDelay:0.2];
    ...
}
```

Bummer: the **wait_fences:** message re-appeared! I think I can't go back to the working solution having an unsatisfied method call - so how can it be done? And/or under which circumstances do these **wait_fences:** messages occur?

Briefly the workflow for my thing is like this:

- viewDidAppear calls its *super* and then my data updater *afterDelay:0.3f*
- the data updater invokes a new thread for the update procedure
- the new thread creates and displays the alert with spinner on the main thread and then runs for some seconds
- the new thread performs a finishing procedure on the main thread and is done
- the finisher dismisses the alert as described above (with **wait_fences:**) and refreshes the display if needed
- the rest is idle time ... for the moment being

Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Sorry, I wish I could help you. I am having a very similar problem where I get the same error message right after dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: but I have not worked out how to fix that either.

Comment: Many people say that it's a bug in iOS frameworks (that btw persists even now on 4.3.3 that I'm running on my devices). I haven't done anything to protect from it and my app is in AppStore since a month - so I think Apple doesn't care either...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the reason why thing happens but sort out this problem by changing this line

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:NO];
```

to  this one

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Comment: I've tried it like you suggested - but for me it doesn't work :-(
... using iOS 4.3.3 btw.