# When I create an Alert from another Alert, I get wait_fences: failed to receive reply

Tags: ios

I want to create a alert from a alert. but it crashes.
I use under code to create a alert:

```
{ 
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:inMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];
}
```

error message is :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSError isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x88b84c0'
```

it looks like inMessage has been release. so I change inMessage to @"test test". It works but get out `wait_fences: failed to receive reply:10004003`

How can i do for creating a alert in a alert ?

Comment: IF the NSString is the problem then your shared code will not help us to solve your problem, correct? Please show us your string init and What do you mean by alert from an alert? You mean you are getting a user response inside a alert delegate method and then you are creating one more alert. Am I right?

Comment: `wait_fences` has nothing to do with this crash. It looks like you're doing some `if ([err isEqualToString:@"someTest..."])...` - there's the problem.

Comment: There is nothing special about this NSString, so I not post it out. I print this NSString out using NSLog, so it isn't a nil. and here is the initialize code:             NSString *inMessage = [userInfo objectForKey:@"NSUnderlyingError"];
            NSLog(@"The error is: %@", inMessage);

Comment: about alart from alart: I call the second's alart in the first alart's delegete : - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the issue here is that you have an NSError that is being treated mistakenly as an NSString.

`inMessage` seems to be your NSError object. This slips through the type system at compile time because `userInfo` has no knowledge of the types of its elements.

To fix this, you probably want to get the description of the error message and display that instead with something like

```
NSString *inMessage = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"NSUnderlyingError"] localizedDescription];
```

Comment: yes, you are correct. it doesn't crash now. but it shows :wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Comment: @kevinyoung I believe that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241894 might help with that. It seems there are a few things that could cause that message.

Comment: sorry, other code causes this "wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003". Not the second alert. thank you !